# How to do the handle authentication in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using the following code to check if the user is currently authenticated to access a certain route. But it doesn't work as it always goes into the way of being not authed. I checked the authenticate() method and it did work by returning true. Could you please look at this and figure out why it is failed? Thanks in advance.

```
const auth = {
    authenticate() {
      fetch('/isAuth')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (json.code === 200) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
      })
    }
  }

  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      auth.authenticate() === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Route path="/notAuthed" exact component={notAuthed} />
    )} />
  )

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />

      <PrivateRoute path='/' component={Index} />

    </Switch>
  );
```

Comment: Where is your authenticate function comming from it will be very useful if you show where you are importing from, otherwise people will get confuse if you are using an specific framework or if that is a function you've built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a state variable to store the result of auth as `fetch` is asynchronous `auth.authenticate` won't return the desired value. You can re-render when fetching is done.

```js
const [isAuthenticate, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);
const auth = {
    authenticate() {
      fetch('/isAuth')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (json.code === 200) {
            setIsAuthenticated(true)
          } else {
            setIsAuthenticated(false)
          }
      })
    }
  }
```

Then you can initialize the routes like this:-

```js
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated === null?<LoadingSpinner/>:isAuthenticated
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Route path="/notAuthed" exact component={notAuthed} />
    )} />
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your help! It works when I try using `isAuthenticated === null?auth.authenticate():isAuthenticated`. For re-rendering, how can I know when it will be re-rendered and what's the re-rendering process?

Comment: Whenever you change a state variable in react using `setState` (here it is `setIsAuthenticated`), the component is re-rendered.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your so helpful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
authenticate() {
  fetch('/isAuth')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (json.code === 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  })
}
```

The method above fetches the isAuth endpoint of your app and checks if the response is 200 == OK.

If isAuth is not found or returns a different HTTP response code in general, the method will return false and thus signal that the user is not authenticated.

You would have to point fetch to a route that exists and checks the authentication of the user.

And because the method uses fetch(**) you would also have to await the response. More on that : https://dev.to/johnpaulada/synchronous-fetch-with-asyncawait